# Problems with some radio buttons in html forms

Tags: css, html, forms, button

I am trying to align this radio buttons on my form, but for some reason they are kinda big and the texts are way above.

Here is my html page:

```
    <div id="sabores">
                               <form action="" method="post">
                            <input type="radio" name="txt_sabor"  value="natural" class="radiobtn" /> Natural </br>
                            <input type="radio" name="txt_sabor"  value="laranja_com_acerola" class="radiobtn" /> Laranja com Acerola </br>
                            <input type="radio" name="txt_sabor"  value="morango" class="radiobtn" /> Morango </br>
                            <input type="radio" name="txt_sabor"  value="limao" class="radiobtn" /> Limão </br>
                            <input type="radio" name="txt_sabor"  value="acai_com_guarana" class="radiobtn" /> Açaí com Guaraná</br>
                            <input type="radio" name="txt_sabor"  value="uva" class="radiobtn" /> Uva </br>
                            <input type="radio" name="txt_sabor"  value="abacaxi" class="radiobtn" /> Abacaxi </br> 
    </form>

</div>
```

and here is my CSS:

```
#sabores{
    width: 370px;
    height: 215px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #fff;   
    color: #667;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#sabores h2{
    width: 364px;
    color: #333;s
}

#sabores .radiobtn{
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  display: block;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  vertical-align:bottom;
   margin-top: 10px;
}
```

[image: What I have]

Comment: Check if there is any style for `input` elements, as i see no problems. Use Dev Tools.

Comment: Don't use `<br>` for spacing, use margins/padding. Also use `label` when dealing with inputs instead of raw text.

Comment: FYI. Your `<br />`'s are incorrect. The slash to self-close them should be at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your have mistype your `br`, instead of `<br />`. And to correct your problem and add a good accessibility practice at same time you can wrap your radio button with text in a `label`. You can use paragraphs `<p>` instead of `<br />` too. And remove your `clear: left; float:left` you don't need to precise `display:block` if your element is floating.

```
#sabores .radiobtn{
    width: 15px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

<div id="sabores">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="txt_sabor_natural"><!-- for with id value of input inside it-->
            <input type="radio" name="txt_sabor" id="txt_sabor_natural" value="natural" class="radiobtn" /> Natural </label><br />
        <label for="laranja">
            <input type="radio" name="txt_sabor" id="laranja" value="laranja_com_acerola" class="radiobtn" /> Laranja com Acerola</label><br />
        <label for="morango">
            <input type="radio" name="txt_sabor" id="morango" value="morango" class="radiobtn" /> Morango </label><br />
        <label for="limao">
            <input type="radio" name="txt_sabor" id="limao" value="limao" class="radiobtn" /> Limão </label><br />
        <label for="acai_com_guarana">
            <input type="radio" name="txt_sabor" id="acai_com_guarana" value="acai_com_guarana" class="radiobtn" /> Açaí com Guaraná </label><br />
        <label for="uva">
            <input type="radio" name="txt_sabor" id="uva" value="uva" class="radiobtn" /> Uva </label><br />
        <label for="abacaxi">
            <input type="radio" name="txt_sabor" id="abacaxi" value="abacaxi" class="radiobtn" /> Abacaxi </label><br /> 
    </form>
</div>
```

Better solution is to use an unordered list `ul` with `li` for each couple label + input or paragraphs, and remove your fixed height from sabores `div` :

```
<div id="sabores">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <p>
            <label for="txt_sabor_natural"><!-- for with id value of input inside it-->
                <input type="radio" name="txt_sabor" id="txt_sabor_natural" value="natural" class="radiobtn" /> Natural </label></p>
        <p>
            <label for="laranja">
                <input type="radio" name="txt_sabor" id="laranja" value="laranja_com_acerola" class="radiobtn" /> Laranja com Acerola</label></p>
        <p>
            <label for="morango">
                <input type="radio" name="txt_sabor" id="morango" value="morango" class="radiobtn" /> Morango </label></p>
        <p>
            <label for="limao">
                <input type="radio" name="txt_sabor" id="limao" value="limao" class="radiobtn" /> Limão </label></p>
        <p>
            <label for="acai_com_guarana">
                <input type="radio" name="txt_sabor" id="acai_com_guarana" value="acai_com_guarana" class="radiobtn" /> Açaí com Guaraná </label></p>
        <p>
            <label for="uva">
                <input type="radio" name="txt_sabor" id="uva" value="uva" class="radiobtn" /> Uva </label></p>
        <p>
            <label for="abacaxi">
                <input type="radio" name="txt_sabor" id="abacaxi" value="abacaxi" class="radiobtn" /> Abacaxi </label></p> 
    </form>
</div>
```

With style :

```
/*previous style*/

#sabores{
    width: 370px;
    /*height: 215px; don't need*/ 
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #fff;   
    color: #667;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#sabores .radiobtn{
    width: 15px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

#sabores p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, all the answers helped, but this one will help me not make this mistake again and organize my code in a better way

Answer (score 3):

Make the following changes to this class:

```
#sabores .radiobtn{
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  /*
  Remove following css properties
  display: block;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
 */
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/33kf1roh/1/)

Comment: Sorry, just realised that my solution was essentially the same as yours so I've removed it. Have a +1 ;)

Comment: You didn't give +1 :P

Answer (score 1):

Please pay more attention the follow class:

```
#sabores .radiobtn{
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  display: block;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  vertical-align:bottom;
   margin-top: 10px;
}
```

as you see, you use these attributes:
`display:block; clear: left; float: left;`
It makes your `input` Element out of page flow, so you can remove these attribute and everything will be ok!

I advise you can read it about Visual formatting model.([click here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats))